# Error on an event on drupal commerce

Tags: email, drupal, drupal-commerce

I have made an event when a person completes an order to be sent an e-mail to me with his/her order something that was not an event at first.But I keep getting this error when someone completes the order at my commerce site.Although the e-mail is sent to me.Could you please help me?

Notice: Undefined index: pending rules_action_mail() (line 90 /home/content/60/9584160/html/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/rules/modules/system.eval.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: pending rules_action_mail() (line 90 /home/content/60/9584160/html/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/rules/modules/system.eval.inc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search on the error message reveals that you may just need to apply a patch: 
http://drupal.org/node/1490136

Or better yet update your Rules module to the latest version if necessary.